# UIImagePickerController in source type Camera with allowsEditing to YES causes a “Terminated due to memory pressure” in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I use UIImagePickerController in a standard way for getting picture from the camera app inside my own app.

```
FSImagePickerViewController *imagePicker = [[FSImagePickerViewController alloc] init];

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing=YES;
imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

`FSImagePickerViewController` is an empty ImagePickerViewController subclass with only portrait allowed.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"Let's go");
}
```

. Now After taking the picture I touch choose an the app crashes :

> Terminated due to memory pressure

Here are some clues :

- the “Let's go” mark is never reached
- The same code with `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` as source works
- I can't debut it with instruments
- This code began to crash with iOS7.0 (worked fine before)
- When I set allowsEditing to NO it works
- With the video mediaType it works

My question is : could some of confirm this is an iOS 7.0 bug ? Or this the code above works on your device ?

Comment: Not at all. I'm not facing any actual memory error. It seems to be an SDK bug from a precise framework in a precise use. Before posting this as a bug to Apple I need confirmation from other dev.

Comment: Before voting this question as a duplicate please read both question and the answer of the other question...

Comment: Have you used the instruments to check the performance? Can you post your instruments data?

Comment: "I can't debut it with instruments" because the bug is not related with the amount of memory used before the UIImagePickerController and there is no memory Allocation increase before the crash. (15.69MB for the last test)

Comment: What I am stating is that you use instruments to figure out the memory usage with your `allowsEditing` set to `NO` and set to `YES` and see how much the memory jumps. I would also recommend creating a blank test project with just an imagePicker and seeing if that works. If you post a bug to apple they will request this.

Comment: Yes same bug in new project and no memory allocation jump at all before the crash. I think there is an infinite loop somewhere in apple's code.

Comment: Can you post a link to the test project you created so we can play around with it?

Comment: I found it the wantsFullScreen which has been deprecated on iOS 7.0 removing the line works. The project is here : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z5mmeoxg2pnrb2f/HETUc73gF7